# No tables found in database after SQL import

Tags: mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin, xampp, bitnami

I'm using the bitnami stack for WordPress on Ubuntu 16.04

I cleared the DB to import an SQL dump in order to clone a site and I get a confirmation message saying:

*Import has been successfully finished, 1239 queries executed. (gailfosl_wordpress1.sql)*

But when I got to the database it says:

*No tables found in database.*

I tried the following:
chown -R mysql.mysql /var/lib/mysql/
but the directory doesn't exist.

I am pretty new to working with this on Linux so please be kind :smile:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution in order to import a WordPress Site is to install the All-In-One-WP-Migration-Plugin and let that plugin to do all the database and files migrations needed.

I recommend you to install it on a fresh Bitnami WordPress Stack and migrate your WP Site using it. You can find more information at the link below:

https://docs.bitnami.com/installer/apps/wordpress/#how-to-install-the-all-in-one-wp-migration-plugin